# Can't read JSON from .txt and convert back to JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have a `.txt` with `JSON` formatted content, that I would like to read, convert it to a `JSON` object and then log the result. I could read the file and I'm really close, but unfortunately `json_data` is a string object instead of a `JSON` object/dictionary.  I assume it's something trivial, but I have no idea, because I'm new to `Python`, so I would really appreciate if somebody could show me the right solution.

```
import json

filename = 'html-json.txt'
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:    
    jsonContentTxt = f.readlines()

json_data = json.dumps(jsonContentTxt)
print (json_data)
```

Comment: `my_jsn = json.load(f)` if you have json in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consult the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for the `json` module. The Python docs are generally pretty great and this is no exception.

`f.readlines()` will read the lines of `f` points to—in your case, `html-json.txt`—and return those lines as a string. So `jsonContentTxt` is a string in JSON *format*.

If you simply want to print this string, you could just `print jsonContentTxt`. On the other hand, if you want to load that JSON into a Python data structure, manipulate it, and then output it, you could do something like this (which uses `json.load`, a [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) that takes a file-like object and returns an object such as a `dict` or `list` depending on the JSON):

```
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:    
    json_content = json.load(f)

# do stuff with json_content, e.g. json_concent['foo'] = 'bar'

# then when you're ready to output:
print json.dumps(json_content)
```

You may also want to use the `indent` argument to `json.dumps` (link [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump)) which will give you a nicely-formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [2.7 documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or the [3.5 documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html):

```
json.loads(json_as_string)  # Deserializes a string to a json heirarchy
```

Once you have a deserialized form you can convert it back to json with a dump:

```
json.dump(json_as_heirarchy)
```